# How to use LINQ Group by on XElement attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

`var seriesonfo` contains following XML,

```
    <series id="S000002334Member">
      <class id="C000006118Member" />
    </series>
    <series id="S000002334Member">
      <class id="C000006119Member" />
    </series>
```

C# Code to Group "series" nodes based on "id" attribute:

```
var result = new XElement("SC",
new[]
     {
       new XElement("seriesAndClassInfo", seriesonfo.GroupBy(a => a.Element("series").Attribute("id")))
     }
```

Expected XML after grouping:

```
   <series id="S000002334Member">
      <class id="C000006118Member" />
      <class id="C000006119Member" />
    </series>
```

Group by not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you need to group by the (string) `Value` of the attribute, not the attribute itself.

Because when you compare `XAttribute`s by reference, they will be seen as different even though they have the same text value. So grouping doesn't work.

Working code:

```
// (I added "root", otherwise the xml is invalid)
string original = "<root><series id=\"S000002334Member\"><class id=\"C000006118Member\" /></series><series id=\"S000002334Member\"><class id=\"C000006119Member\" /></series></root>";            
XElement originalXml = XElement.Parse(original);

var groups = originalXml              
    .Descendants("series")
    .GroupBy(a => a.Attribute("id").Value); // that's the important bit...

IEnumerable<XElement> afterGrouping = groups
    .Select(
        grp => // for each group...
            new XElement( // ...create a new element
                "series", 
                new XAttribute("id", grp.Key), 
                grp.Select(each => each.Element("class")))); // containing all "class" elements from the group

XElement final = new XElement("final", afterGrouping); // just adding root element again

// and the result is:
//
// <final>
//     <series id="S000002334Member">
//         <class id="C000006118Member" />
//         <class id="C000006119Member" />
//     </series>
// </final>
```

Comment: I'm adding a new attribute named name to the series element, how to do i display it in the output?

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = doc.Descendants("series").GroupBy(s => s.Attribute("id").Value)
            .Select(g => new XElement("series", new XAttribute("id", g.Key), 
                        g.SelectMany(c=>c.Descendants("class"))));
```

Comment: I'd go with that one if 1 of the `series` had multiple `class` subelements. The difference between my answer and this one (besides of mine being more step-by-step) lies in using `g.SelectMany(c => c.Descendants("class"))` where I used `grp.Select(each => each.Element("class"))`. `SelectMany` on `Descendants` ensures that no `class` element will be skipped, whereas `Select` and `Element("class")` will only take the **first** `class` element from each `series`. It happens to make no difference for the sample data given by the OP, but it might if there were multiple `class`es under some `series`.

Comment: @Damith - I'm adding a new attribute named name to the series element, how to do i display it in the output?

Comment: And how do you implement something like this Where(s => s.idList == "S0")?